# when iam runing npm run dev it showing me this error, how to solve this

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, javascript, ethereum-classic, npm

[![shiva@shiva-VirtualBox:~/sta$ npm run dev

> StarNotary@1.0.0 dev /home/shiva/sta
>   lite-server

** browser-sync config **

```
{
  injectChanges: false,
  files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
  watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
  server: {
    baseDir: [ './src', './build/contracts' ],
    middleware: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ]
  }
}
```

[Browsersync] Access URLs:

```
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.0.2.15:3000
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 ----------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./src
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./build/contracts
[Browsersync] Watching files...
events.js:282
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/shiva/sta/build/contracts'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (internal/fs/watchers.js:169:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1361:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:5)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/shiva/sta/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:5) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/shiva/sta/build/contracts',
  filename: '/home/shiva/sta/build/contracts'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! StarNotary@1.0.0 dev: `lite-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the StarNotary@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shiva/.npm/_logs/2020-03-13T07_43_57_369Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The error message is unrelated to Ethereum, you can try search for a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698613/enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached-how-to-solved-it.